# Directory Search Function C++

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

I'm trying to translate a snippet of C# code to C++/CLI.

C# code:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
DirectoryInfo [] subdirs;
foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dir.GetDirectories())
    Search(subdir.Fullname);
```

I've gotten it up until the final line;

C++ code:

```
System::IO::DirectoryInfo^ dir = gcnew DirectoryInfo(dirbxSearch->Path);
array <System::IO::DirectoryInfo^>^ subdirs;
for each (System::IO::DirectoryInfo^ subdir in dir->GetDirectories())
     Search(subdir->FullName);
```

The problem is that I have no idea where search comes from. Being such an ambiguous word, I haven't been able to find it in any references either. Without the proper inheritance, it can't compile, so I'm a bit stuck.

Answer (score 0):

C# doesn't allow for global functions (scoped outside of a class); the closest you can have is a static function on a type.  Since the function is not scoped to a specific class (i.e. `MyType.Search(subdir.Fullname)`), it must reside in the class hierarchy that your code snippet resides in.

In Visual Studio, right click on the `Search()` identifier and select "Go To Definition" (default shortcut is F12).  If you are not using Visual Studio, you can at least search in the classes that comprise the inheritance structure.

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with Visual Studio, so thanks. My results didn't turn up anything, so I'm thinking that Search is buried somewhere.